# windows phone access rootframe to handle obscured event

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone

I am trying to access windows phone's obscured event, for that I need to get access to rootframe. I am working on a windows phone silverlight 8.1 app. My code is:

```
public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        (Application.Current as App).RootFrame.Obscured += OnObscured;
        (Application.Current as App).RootFrame.Unobscured += OnUnobscured;
    }
```

Above code gives an error "'calltest.App.RootFrame.get' cannot be accessed with an instance reference; qualify it with a type name instead". What's wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`RootFrame` is static, so replace your code by:

```
App.RootFrame.Obscured += OnObscured;
App.RootFrame.Unobscured += OnUnobscured;
```